# Версия ARM у Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, dart

Какая версия у Raspberry Pi 3. Интересуюсь для того, чтобы узнать, можно ли установить dart на свою машинку. Хотелось бы поиграться с этим "товарищем"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот в руках держу **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v.1.2** сборка 2015 года.
На нем `Broadcom BCM2837` что является `64 bit ARMv8`.

Однако знаю, что есть очень много версий Pi 3 Model B. Как минимум 2015, 2016, 2017 года. Перед покупкой нужной версии желательно ознакомиться с характеристикой на все.

Нужное вам вроде есть даже для 1-ой версии малинки: [Building Dart SDK for Raspberry Pi 1](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building-Dart-SDK-for-Raspberry-Pi-1)